# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when using shapefile with arcpy_metadata module

Tags: arcpy, metadata, python-3

I am having an issue with the arcpy_metadata module. I have a simple shapefile I am trying to load into the MetadataEditor:

```
import arcpy, os, sys,env 
import arcpy_metadata as md 
myfeatures = "C:/Workspace/Sandbox/MetadataProject/data/model_domains" 
arcpy.env.workspace = myfeatures 
list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
for item in list: 
    metadata = md.MetadataEditor(item)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I resolve this?

It also seems that since I am running 64-bit version, that features from a `.gdb` won't work becuase they require XSLTransform_conversion, which is only supported in 32-bit.

Comment: Try adding `print(item)`. Dont name the variable `list`, it is a function

Comment: `print(item)` gives me `fluvial.shp`, one of the shapefiles in the model_domains directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer to this question, after contacting one of the developers on their [Github site](https://github.com/ucd-cws/arcpy_metadata/issues/47) is that I was using Python 3.6 with ArcGIS Pro and the module is currently only supported in 2.7. Once I switched to my ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 with Python 2.7 environment, it worked.